# 3D point to 2D point conversion - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm working on building the backend for a geospatial application. It involves the storage of latitude , longitude and altitude (optional).

The column `Location` in the table is of the type - `Location geography(POINtZ,4326)`

The insertion statement 
`"INSERT INTO someTable (Location) VALUES(ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(?)');`

I do not have a problem in inserting a 3d point (in String format) in place of the "?", but how do I go about the case where I have just the longitude and latitude present? For obvious reasons I do not want to manipulate the location string to have a third value (altitude) to be set to zero.

I'm hoping someone could help me to figure this issue out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your column is of 3d-point type (POINTZ). This is why you have to supply it with 3d points. I think there are two ways to solve your problem:

1.Convert your column to `geometry(point, 4326)` (2d-point) type using:

```
alter table someTable
    alter Location type geometry(point, 4326)
        using st_force2d(Location);
```

Then you will be able to insert 2d-points.

2.Modify your insert query like this:

```
INSERT INTO someTable (Location)
    VALUES(st_force3d(ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(?)'));.
```

In this case you pass it 2d-point and query will transform it to 3d-point using zero as third dimension.

If zero value for z-dimension is not an option then you can have a column in your table to show the dimension of the geometry. For example:

```
alter table someTable add geomdim int;
```

Then populate it with current dimension when inserting. For example:

```
with geom_t as (
    select st_geomfromtext('POINT(?)', 4326) as geom
)
insert into someTable(Location, geomdim)
    select st_force3d(geom)::geography, st_coorddim(geom) from geom_t;
```

Comment: Hi @stas, thank you for the input. I feel the second option is not what I wanted since I didnt want the third value to be assumed to be 0. Also, I used tried out the first option as u specified.I check the dimension of location and in case it's 2D, I alter the table to enable insert and then re-alter it to support 3D.But this again stores a 0 as the third value!

Answer (score 1):

PostGIS functions can only support the specific dimension and are not flexible to third coordinate being optional, I've moved on by sticking onto having the data type of `Location` as PointZ and have a check on the dimensionality of location.

If the point is found to be 2D, then the location string is appended with a junk value say `-34567891` to avoid errors on insertion and upon location retrieval, pay heed to parsing these type of location points.